# Multiple criteria replace mysql record with php

Tags: php, mysql

I am collecting data from a html form, submitting the data to mysql using a php script.

However, I can't figure out how to replace/update a record if multiple criteria match.

If a new submitted record from the html form, has the same 'type', 'volume' and 'place_name' as an existing record, it should replace the 'price'.

At this moment, it is just writing a new line with the new data. 
Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks!

Please see my php code below:

```
<?php 

require("config.php");

if(!$con)
{
    echo 'Not Connected To Server';
}
    if(!mysqli_select_db($con,'DB3469638'))
{
    echo 'Database Not Selected';
}



$type= $_POST['type'];
$volume= $_POST['volume'];
$price= $_POST['price'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$place_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['place_name']);
$lat = $_POST['lat'];
$lng = $_POST['lng'];
$location = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['location']);


$sql = "INSERT INTO markers (type, volume, price, place_name, 
        place_Location, email, place_Lat,place_Lng) 
VALUES ('$type','$volume','$price','$place_name',
      '$location','$email','$lat','$lng')";

if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    echo 'Not Inserted';                        
}
    else
{
    header("refresh:4; url=addprice.php");
    echo "<div align='center' style ='font:40px/60px Arial,tahoma,sans- 
    serif;color:#ffffff'> Submitted! <br><br> Redirecting Automatically 
    </div>";


}


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you would want to create a multi-column index in SQL on the columns you don't want to be duplicates:

```
CREATE INDEX multiIndex ON markers (type, volume, place_name);
```

Now you can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` in your PHP:

```
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO markers
        (type, volume, price, place_name, place_Location, email, place_Lat,place_Lng)
    VALUES
        ('$type','$volume','$price','$place_name', '$location','$email','$lat','$lng')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        price = '$price'
";
```

Comment: Where should i place the "create index" line? I can't get it working yet... but it seems like that it would make sense doing it this way.

in this way: will the price be updated if both the type, volume and place name are the same? or just if one of the three is matching?

Comment: You only need to execute the `CREATE INDEX` line once, ever. So use PHPMyAdmin, Adminder or any database admin tool you use to execute the SQL. Optionally, create a temporary PHP script to execute `CREATE INDEX` line and just open it up in your browser one time and make sure it works. From then on, the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` line should work automatically... 2) The price will only be updated if all three of the columns match the same.

Comment: Thanks, i got the sql working now. I executed it in PHPMyAdmin and see it as an index. there is also a grey key behind the column name.

But... it is still not updating the previous record with matching type, volume and place_name... Shouldn't I connect that multiIndex with the "on duplicate key update"? Or how does the PHP input know that it should look at the multiIndex? 

I'm new to PHP and SQL, sorry if i don't understand something the first time :) 
I appreciate your help!

Comment: I made a new index as an unique value. I've got it working now! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should find out if this is a new record, or an update of an existing one. To do this, you must either incorporate `ID`s (recommended) or query the database first (where `type`, `volume` and `place_name` matches with provided one - not recommended).

Beside this, you should avoid SQL injections by not using user input directly in your SQL queries.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm new to php and dont know actually how i could implement this. 
I do have a key primary id key in mysql. but that id is just a numeral count for every new record. not related to either type, volume or place name.

Comment: @JobdeRuiter you might wanna [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your database.